# Why my code prints characters from the BST tree that I didn't put in it. C++

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I have the raw text of Tolkien's book The Lord of the Rings The Fellowship Of The Ring without stop signs like "," "." "-" and no uppercase letters. I want to count the occurrences of all possible combinations of four characters in the text, including spaces.

For example, in the text "one ring to rule them all" there are four words: "one", "ne r", "e ri", "rin", "ring", ..., "all". There will be over 2 million fours in The Lord of the Rings, of course much fewer different fours - for example, the four "frod" will appear many times.

For this purpose, I want to use a BST tree in which the keys will be fours, and I also want to keep an occurrence counter in the nodes. I wrote sample code (it is at the bottom of the page) which creates my tree which contains all the necessary information. For clarity, I implemented a function that prints all fours along with the number of their occurrences. **My problem begins when I notice characters in the printed fours that should not be in the source text**.

EXAMPLE:
[console1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fGb5.png)

`Czworka: |   ˇ| Liczba wystapien: 1`      "`ˇ`" shouldnt be in text!

[console2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svpC5.png)
`Czworka: |  eń| Liczba wystapien: 1`      "`ń`" shouldnt be in text!

translation: "Czworka" mean "Four" and "Liczba wystapien" mean "Number of appearances".
| | are parentheses for four.

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include <windows.h>   ///for checking results in slow-mo


using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string key;
    int count;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};

node *dummy;

node *Add(node* &r, const string& k, node* par=nullptr)
{
    if(!r)
    {
        r = new node;
        r->key = k;
        r->count = 1;
        r->left = r->right = nullptr;
        r->parent = par;
        return r;
    }

    if(r->key == k)
    {
        r->count++;
        return r;
    }

    if(r->key > k) return Add(r->left, k, r);
    return Add(r->right, k, r);
}

void CountOccurrences(node* &root, const string& filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open file: " << filename << endl;
        return;
    }

    string fourChars;
    char currentChar;
    while (file.get(currentChar))
    {
        fourChars += currentChar;

        if (fourChars.length() == 4)
        {
            Add(root, fourChars);
            fourChars.erase(0, 1);  // Usuwa pierwszy znak, przechodząc do kolejnej czwórki
        }
    }

    file.close();
}

void InOrderTraversal(node* r)
{
    if (!r) return;
    InOrderTraversal(r->left);
    cout << "Czworka: |" << r->key << "| Liczba wystapien: " << r->count << endl;
    //Sleep(100);   /// for checking results in slow-mo
    InOrderTraversal(r->right);
}

int main()
{
    node *root = nullptr;
    dummy = new node;
    dummy->right = nullptr;

    
    string filename = "The_Fellowship_Of_The_Ring.txt";

    CountOccurrences(dummy->right, filename);

    InOrderTraversal(dummy->right);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is book text:

[Gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QydU1D_wD6lc8fkPJbuoaVnA3vT6o5b9/view?usp=sharing)  (I couldnt paste this text here because of character limit, but wanted to recreate the conditions in which I encountered the error. If there is any way to include it in this post, please advise.)

I made sure that these characters were not in the text using notepad++ and the text search function.

Comment: Some accented characters do exist in the text. E.g. `ai laurië lantar lassi súrinen`. I haven't looked for the specific ones in your example. My guess would be, the file is encoded in UTF-8, and you in effect interpret it in some other encoding, resulting in [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Comment: Don't expect folk to go to a link to look at a file. Few will take that risk. I didn't, but make sure you are not looking at the file's byte order mark.

Comment: You may want to move node initialization into the node constructor, such as count, and link field initializations.

Comment: *I couldnt paste this text here because of character limit* -- But you didn't even need to have any file I/O.  All you had to do is create a `main` function that simply called `Add` 3 or 4 times with hardcoded 4 character strings that duplicate the issue.  No file I/O needed, plus it would have been a [mcve], plus no external links to files.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Except that I don't know which conglomerations of characters cause the problem. The characters written by me should not appear there. I will try to test with different text fragments for this purpose. As soon as I manage to figure something out, I will edit this post quickly.

Comment: @urshuk If you run the program multiple times, do you get the same bad output, each and every time?  If so, there is a pattern that you could be using to narrow the problem down.  Maybe keep track of the position in the file and print this out, so that you know where things start to go bad?  If the output is different or random when you run the program multiple times, then the issue is more than likely your BST having bugs.

Comment: Also `Sleep(100);` -- `#include <windows.h>` -- Is this necessary?  Not only is it probably not necessary, the code won't compile if someone were to take the time to compile it under a non-Windows OS for testing.

Comment: `struct node` -- Add an `int64_t filepos;` or similar member, and populate it with the current file position.  This is just an example of getting a better picture of where things in the file start to go "wrong".  You will now have nodes that contain more information instead of simply a `key` and `count`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is not, but i have that piece of code for checking results. Ill comment it then.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good idea with filepos, ill try it.

Comment: Hope you are calling `delete` in your actual code else there will be memory leaks.